# Save SelectItem client to projet object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have a `projet` object and I need to save it to a SelectItem `clients` object. How do I code this?

```
public Projet projet;
public List<Client> clients;
```

we have a Xhtml code

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{details.projet.client}">

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="----Choisir Votre Client ---------" itemValue="-1"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{details.clients}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.nom_prenom}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <p:commandButton value="Choisir" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

I need to save the selected item of `clients` object to a `projet` object. How do I code this in ManagedBean `details`?

Comment: @Balus C , i not need to display into selectonemenu but i need when onclick button command the item selected of selectonemenu ( type Client) , the  value inserted in class projet into DB

Comment: It's covered in the top answer of the duplicate. Did you read it from top to bottom?

Comment: My problem is not display in the selectonemenu(the display is done) ,but  my problem is when I click on the "select" button, I prefer to assign the selected value to the table selectonemenu 'project'.

Comment: So you're saying that you don't have a JSF related problem? I.e. you already have the `client` variable set with right value thanks to JSF and you just wanted to save the `client` variable in the database?

Comment: yes , i talk about that

Comment: I do not know what is the necessary code to the method of choisirClient () in the bean

Comment: JSF is a MVC framework for HTML form based applications, not a database persistence framework. For that you normally use JPA or perhaps vanilla JDBC. Just start off with the `client` variable. JSF has at that point already done its job of providing you the submitted HTML form value in a Java variable and is irrelevant as to persisting that variable in the database.